# Do we need to change sign-in URL work in Amplify (or Cognito in general) for my React app?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

When I started using (learning) AWS Amplify, Amplify's setup wizard gives the following step:

`Enter your redirect signin URI: http://localhost:3000/ (this can be updated later for production environments)`

At the end of the amplify auth configuration, Amplify outputs the following configuration strings:

```
Hosted UI Endpoint: https://myreactapp-dev.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/

Test Your Hosted UI Endpoint: https://myreactapp-dev.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=34dqhtm4o5odkbtbe2723da9&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/
```

And my React app worked during my tests. How should I change the callback URI in production? What URL should I use (*** according to "this can be updated later for production environments"***)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the hosted sign-in UI, you can configure your callback url on the AWS Cognito console:

**Services** > **Cognito** > **Manage User Pools** > *[Your user pool]* > **App Integration** > **App Client Settings**

You should add the full url of the callback you're using for your hosted website, for example: `https://example.com/`.